# Unable to delete GKE cluster created by Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am working on a Terraform script to create a cluster (tf code below). It gets 90% done then errors. When trying to apply another change or delete this cluster, I run into lack of permission. I made every account in the project Owner and still have the issue. How do I clear this out?

Error:

```
(1) (1) (1) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.instanceGroupManagers.delete' permission for 'projects/gke-eval-319218/zones/us-east4-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-hello-default-pool-6e16e226-grp' (2) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.instanceGroupManagers.delete' permission for 'projects/gke-eval-319218/zones/us-east4-b/instanceGroupManagers/gke-hello-default-pool-a00f72b6-grp' (3) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.instanceGroupManagers.delete' permission for 'projects/gke-eval-319218/zones/us-east4-c/instanceGroupManagers/gke-hello-default-pool-ea0634bc-grp' (2) (1) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.projects.get' permission for 'projects/gke-eval-319218' (2) retry budget exhausted (5 attempts): Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.routes.list' permission for 'projects/gke-eval-319218' (3) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.firewalls.delete' permission for 'projects/gke-eval-319218/global/firewalls/gke-hello-c4849243-all' (4) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.firewalls.delete' permission for 'projects/gke-eval-319218/global/firewalls/gke-hello-c4849243-ssh' (5) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.firewalls.delete' permission for 'projects/gke-eval-319218/global/firewalls/gke-hello-c4849243-vms' (2) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.subnetworks.get' permission for 'projects/gke-eval-319218/regions/us-east4/subnetworks/default'.
```

Script that created this mess:

```
variable project_id {}
variable zones {}
variable region {}
variable name {}
variable network {}
variable subnetwork {}
variable ip_range_pods { default = null }
variable ip_range_services { default = null }

locals {
  service_account = "${var.name}-sa"
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  project = var.project_id
  account_id   = "${local.service_account}"
  display_name = "${var.name} cluster service account"
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "service_account_iam" {
  project = var.project_id
  role = "roles/container.admin"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${local.service_account}@${var.project_id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
}

module "gke" {
  source                     = "terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google"
  project_id                 = var.project_id
  name                       = var.name
  region                     = var.region
  zones                      = var.zones
  network                    = var.network
  subnetwork                 = var.subnetwork
  ip_range_pods              = var.ip_range_pods
  ip_range_services          = var.ip_range_services
  http_load_balancing        = true
  horizontal_pod_autoscaling = false
  network_policy             = false
  service_account            = "${local.service_account}@${var.project_id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

  node_pools = [
    {
      name                      = "default-pool"
      machine_type              = "e2-medium"
      min_count                 = 3
      max_count                 = 20
      local_ssd_count           = 0
      disk_size_gb              = 100
      auto_repair               = true
      auto_upgrade              = true
      preemptible               = false
      initial_node_count        = 10
    },
  ]

  node_pools_oauth_scopes = {
    all = []

    default-pool = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    ]
  }

  node_pools_labels = {
    all = {}

    default-pool = {
      default-pool = true
    }
  }

  node_pools_metadata = {
    all = {}

    default-pool = {
      node-pool-metadata-custom-value = "my-node-pool"
    }
  }

  node_pools_taints = {
    all = []

    default-pool = [
      {
        key    = "default-pool"
        value  = true
        effect = "PREFER_NO_SCHEDULE"
      },
    ]
  }

  node_pools_tags = {
    all = []

    default-pool = [
      "default-pool",
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The identity that you assigned the Owner role is not the identity that Terraform is using. Edit your question with details on where this code is running and how you authorized Terraform. If you are using ADC (Application Default Credentials) from an environment variable or from the CLI **gcloud**, double-check the identity used.

Comment: It was running under a service account I created named 'terraform'. I made *all* the accounts owners and still couldn't resolve. I gave up and moved to a clean project.

Answer (score 1):

You might require to enable API if you are forgetting any

like

```
gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com
```

also, make sure service account you are have the role or policy attached.

```
 --role  roles/compute.admin
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The API had to be enabled to create the cluster - but to be sure I ran your suggestion and saw no improvement. Service account has Owner role.

Comment: @jws please try disabling and enabling API once : `gcloud services disable container.googleapis.com --project <name>`

Comment: I'm stuck there since I have another functioning cluster using files.googleapis.com

Comment: You've convinced me to just begin a new project from scratch and walk away from this undeletable situation.

Comment: haha...! That would be better creating a new project, GCP issue undeleted resources contact support please...!